# vega not plotting the data

Tags: kibana, vega

I am brand new to Vega and I was trying to plot some charts on Vega (plugin ElasticSearch and Kibana). Below is the simple visulization I am trying to plot. I am following through the documentation to connect the existing data, however I am unable to get the visuals. It just shows Y and X axis labeled from the code below with blank plots. What am I doing wrong?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json"
    "data": {
        url: {
                %context%: true
                index: test-data
                }
      format: {property: "hits.hits"}
            },
    "mark": {"type":"bar"}
    "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DEPT", "type": "ordinal"},
        "y": {"field": "SALES", "type": "quantitative"}
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The specification needs to be valid JSON. There are numerous things in your specification that make it invalid; for example:

- all strings need to be enclosed in quotes (e.g. `url` and `format`)
- all items need to be separated by commas (applies to nearly every line of your specification)

Finally, even if you change those syntax errors, the content of your specification doesn't follow the schema: for example, the `"url"` and the `"format"` properties of `"data"` both should be strings.

I would suggest beginning with the [vega-lite tutorials](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/getting_started.html), and go from there, modifying what you learn to work with your own data.